# Format current date to show day of the week

Tags: java, android, date

I want to show the current date in my application like this: 
Thu, May 2, 2013

I already have the following code to get the current date

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

Time time = new Time();
time.set(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
             c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

How can I format this Time object to the string I need?

Comment: Try using SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); For the detailed explanation of the values uses use [this link](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what you want

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println("Current date in String Format: " + strDate);
```

Where strDate can be displayed in your textView or whatever

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use it.

This example displays the names of the weekdays in short form with the help of DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays() method of DateFormatSymbols class.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Date dt = new Date(1000000000000L);

      DateFormat[] dtformat = new DateFormat[6];
      dtformat[0] = DateFormat.getInstance();
      dtformat[1] = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
      dtformat[2] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
      dtformat[3] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
      dtformat[4] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
      dtformat[5] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

      for(DateFormat dateform : dtformat)
         System.out.println(dateform.format(dt));
  }
}
```

**output:**

```
9/9/01 7:16 AM
Sep 9, 2001
Sep 9, 2001
Sunday, September 9, 2001
September 9, 2001
9/9/01
```

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/date_format.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd,yyyy");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));              
Log.e("formattedDate",formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd,MM,yyyy");

String strdate = dateformat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Oops, I'm a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use java.text.SimpleDateFormat instead.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date=new Date();
    String format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,MMM d,yyyy ").format(date);
    System.out.println(format);
}
```